# Is there a Battery indicator?

Tags: 11.04, indicator, battery

Generally when using my laptop, in Maverick the battery icon used to show up in the panel giving me an indication of the battery status and also allowing me to set the performance of the machine like Performance, Normal, On Demand, Power Save etc.

However I have Ubuntu natty installed on my dell inspiron 1525 and it did not show any battery info on the panel. This can be seen from the screenshot below..

[image]

**Is there a default battery indicator for Natty?**

Comment: Can you be a bit more descriptive of the problem or possibly post a screen shot? I have a battery indicator (on Natty) so I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: I apologize for the lack of detail..I've described it better now..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go to **Power Management Preferences** and click the tab labelled **General** then check the box **Always Display Battery Icon** in the **Notification Area**

Answer (score 2):

You can follow scouser73's instructions on default behaviour of the battery status. Or you can add extra bit of features with [this](http://live.gnome.org/BatteryStatus) applet. Instructions on using it with indicator system of ubuntu is also mentioned. If it is not present for your ubuntu distribution just download deb file and install.

For natty: Just download maverick version of [deb](https://launchpad.net/~iaz/+archive/battery-status/+files/battery-status_0.1.1-0ubuntu2_all.deb) file from ppa and add /usr/lib/battery-status/battery-status --indicator to your startup application. You should have `never display an icon` in your power manager settings for this to work.